# Ansible loop of nested item in results

Tags: dictionary, ansible

deploying an ubuntu 18.04 server with ansible I came across the following issue:

Some packages I want to install are neither in the official repos, nor in a PPA. So I have to download and install them from github.

I check wether a package is already installed with `dpkg-query -W` and run the following install task only if the return code is `1`. Like so:

```
# ripgrep
- name: "Check if ripgrep is installed"
  command: dpkg-query -W ripgrep
  register: ripgrep_dpkg_check
  failed_when: ripgrep_dpkg_check.rc > 1
  changed_when: ripgrep_dpkg_check.rc == 1

- name: "Install ripgrep from github
  apt:
     deb: "https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases/download/11.0.2/ripgrep_11.0.2.deb"
  when: ripgrep_dpkg_check.rc == 1
```

This is fine for a single package, but for multiple packages it gets tedious.

So I thought about looping over a hash containing my package info like this:

```
extrapackages:
 - { name: ripgrep , version: 2.0, url: awfawf }
 - { name: fd, version: 1.4, url: awfdawf }
```

and then looping over it:

```
- name: "Check if package is installed"
  command: "dpkg-query -W {{ item.name }}"
  register: dpkg_check
  loop: "{{ extrapackages }}"
```

which gives me:

```
"dpkg_check": {
    "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": [
                "dpkg-query",
            "-W",
            "ripgrep"
            ],
            "delta": "0:00:00.015585",
            "end": "2019-11-27 17:18:42.951019",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "dpkg-query -W ripgrep",
                    "_uses_shell": false,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                    "strip_empty_ends": true,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "name": "ripgrep",
                "url": "awfawf",
                "version": 2.0
            },
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-11-27 17:18:42.935434",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "ripgrep\t11.0.2",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "ripgrep\t11.0.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": [
                "dpkg-query",
            "-W",
            "fd"
            ],
            "delta": "0:00:00.015857",
            "end": "2019-11-27 17:18:43.137177",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "dpkg-query -W fd",
                    "_uses_shell": false,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                    "strip_empty_ends": true,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "name": "fd",
                "url": "awfdawf",
                "version": 1.4
            },
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-11-27 17:18:43.121320",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "fd\t7.4.0",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "fd\t7.4.0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to run apt for all loop items, that have `rc = 1`. In pseudo code I want something like:

```
for package in dpkg_check.results:
    if package.rc = 1:
        apt install package.item.url
```

Is something like this possible in ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_query. For example

```
- apt:
    name: "{{ dpkg_check.results|
              json_query('[?rc == `1`].item.url') }}"
```

Test it first with debug. For example

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ dpkg_check.results|
             json_query('[?rc == `1`].item.url') }}"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @Vladimir Botka, this is exactly what I was looking for.

My working solution:

```
- name: "Check if extra packages are installed"                                                                                                                                                                               
  command: "dpkg-query -W {{ item.name }}"                                                                                                                                                                                    
  register: dpkg_check                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  loop: "{{ extrapackages }}"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  failed_when: dpkg_check.rc > 1                                                                                                                                                                                              
  changed_when: dpkg_check.rc == 1                                                                                                                                                                                            

- name: "Install missing extra packages"                                                                                                                                                                                      
  apt:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  deb: "{{ item }}"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  loop: "{{ dpkg_check.results|json_query('[?rc == `1`].item.url') }}"                                                                                                                                                        
  when: dpkg_check.changed
```